# Best practice to generate the settings view of an UI

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

My question is not specific to Python/PyQt4 but it's the language and api I'm currently using. I want to know if there is a library to automatically generate GUI forms from public parameters of an object. It would be very useful for automatic settings generation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for searching fully suited library. Also, i think, it is unnecessary and waste of time. There are lots of frustrating issue, such as localization settings, number format settings, validation issue etc.

I recommend, use Qt designer form layout to create quickly a form. 
Then use pyqt4/QValidation and u can use some regular expression(python new regex module better than QRegExp).

At the and of, manage custom objects via jsonpickle or just python pickle.